# Вместо буквы русской буквы Р отображается "?"

Tags: php

```
            $enc = 'UTF-8';
            $word =  "РАЗРАБОТАТЬ";
            $word = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $word);
            $word = mb_convert_case($word, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
            $count = mb_strlen($word, $enc); 
            $new_word = mb_substr($word, 0, ($count - 1), $enc);
            $new_word = $new_word . mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($word,($count - 1), 1, $enc), $enc);
            $randomLine = $new_word;
```

Мне нужно чтобы регистр 1ой и последней буквы был Верхний, вот только буква р все время отображается как "?"

Comment: [Определенно, дело не в коде.](https://3v4l.org/IpLIc)

Comment: Чтобы не указывать "UTF-8" для каждой mb_* функции, установите кодировку для этих функций функцией mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8") в начале скрипта. Также для всех шаблонов, работающих с UTF-8 добавляйте модификатор u: preg_replace('/\s+/u', '', $word); Попробуйте скопировать строку "РАЗРАБОТАТЬ" с этой страницы и вставьте в свой код.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1)Вначале PHP файла пропишите

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

2)Создайте файл .htaccess
И в нем пропишите

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Лучше использовать второй способ, потому что кодировка устанавливается для большинства случаев, нежели прописывать каждый раз заголовок

Comment: забыл сказать, в заголовке кодировка прописана

Answer (score -1):

Из комментариев к документации `php.net`

```
function mb_strrev($str){
    $r = '';
    for ($i = mb_strlen($str); $i>=0; $i--) {
        $r .= mb_substr($str, $i, 1);
    }
    return $r;
}

function mb_ucfirst($str) {
    $fc = mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($str, 0, 1));
    return $fc.mb_substr($str, 1);
}

$word =  "РАЗРАБОТАТЬ";
$result = mb_strrev(mb_ucfirst(mb_strrev(mb_ucfirst(mb_strtolower($word))))); // РазработатЬ
```